# Preview to Touchscreen

Tags: display

Im using Rasberry pi 3 , along with a 14 inch display monitor connected via HDMI port , i used python code to capture image from the pi camera , preview it and save it in a folder , but when i switched to Touch screen display the preview was not working but images are getting stored , ive read that the preview output is given directly to the HDMI port , is there any way to change it to Touch screen?? In the documentation [https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#the-preview-doesn-t-work-on-my-pitft-screen](http://Documentation) Its given that it is possible in some Adafruit projects . However is there a way to make it work in XPT2046 Display ?

Comment: I'm a little unsure as to your setup. Can you confirm that you're using one 14" display which is connected to the Pi's HDMI output and displays previews correctly, and a second display (XPT2046) which is connected to the Pi's GPIO/SPI pins and doesn't display previews?

Comment: @goobering Actually at first i tried it by using the separate monitor connected through a HDMI port , so the preview of camera was working .after that i tried the same code with XPT 2046 touch display the preview is not working but im getting the images stored in the folder .Read the link in the question you will understand the problem better

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there's been no change to the pi camera previewing system - I don't think this is possible due to the nature of the hardware. There's a kinda sorta workaround somewhere that I've linked to in the past, but it's going to take me a while to find it.

Comment: @goobering Thank you , please let me know if it is possible

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=45059

Comment: @Steve Robillard  Ive tried it $ git clone https://github.com/tasanakorn/rpi-fbcp.git
$ cd rpi-fbcp
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
Run
$ ./fbcp & but after running it all im getting is a blank screen .on pitft